# aws snapshot to new db

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it possible to create a new db from a snapshot image without migrating it? I have a snapshot of mysql db that I would like to host temporarily to get back some entries. I only seem to have the options to restore it or migrate it to a different version of sql.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you restore from a DB snapshot, it will create a **new RDS instance** and have your mysql db setup in it. You can use the connection string to connect to the db via a mysql client and interact with the data.

Here is a [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.RestoringFromSnapshot.html) on how to restore a db instance from db snapshot.